# Disable Dynamic Button in GridView Row Databound

Tags: asp.net

I want to disable Button Control which is bound to that Grid.
I'm using   btnTestMod.Enabled=false;
But it is showing  "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."   Please suggest to correct.

```
protected void gvRootModule_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button btnTestMod = ((Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnlessontest"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where have you created that button? Why have you omitted the line `btnTestMod.Enabled=false;` from the code above? That's confusing.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void gvRootModule_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var button = e.Row.FindControl("btnlessontest") as Button;
        if(button == null) return;

        button.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How could that help? If he gets a `NullReferenceException` the solution is not to `return` but to find the reason.

Comment: `DataRow` represents more than just the actual rows that contain data. therefore the row may not contain the control and you need to check for NRE.

Comment: No, since you've checked for `DataControlRowType.DataRow` you're only getting rows with  data and all or none should contain that button. That would only make sense if he has created the button in the header or footer.